# Dynamically Colored Shapes in Powerpoint using VBA

Tags: vba, colors, powerpoint, shapes

I want a color-coded map of Europe in a presentation.

The individual countries should be colored green, yellow or red depending on a certain risk-score. I thought this would be doable by linking the PPT to an Excel and then doing some conditional formatting.

I created a map consisting of the European country shapes and named each shape accordingly. I created the dynamic coloring in Excel using code like this:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Range("B2") = "opposed" Then
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Austria")).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
Else
    If Range("B2") = "undecided" Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Austria")).Select
        Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent4
    Else
        If Range("B2") = "approving" Then
            ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Austria")).Select
            Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent6
        End If
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

I put the risk assessment ("opposed", "undecided", "approving") into a column, then ask what that value is, then change the color of the shape accordingly. The code works. If any value is changed, the map changes.

Now I need this in PowerPoint. PowerPoint VBA seems to be quite different, and I couldn't find anything on how to make this work. I tried the following as a proof of concept:

```vb
Sub coloring()
If ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Rect1").TextFrame.TextRange.Text.Value = "RED" Then ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Rect2").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End Sub
```

**How I'd like to do it**:
Create one (hidden) slide which contains all the information (in text boxes or a table with cells or something like that).
Create multiple slides which refer to the content of the hidden slide and display color-coded information based on the content on the hidden slide.

Answer (score 1):

Since VBA for each app closely follows the app's own object model, each will seem odd if you're accustomed to a different app's OM but not the one you're working in.

Here's a working example. Your code was almost there:

```
Sub coloring()

' Using With/End With can save a lot of typing:
With ActivePresentation.Slides(1)

If .Shapes("Rect1").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "RED" Then
    ' It's a good idea to make sure the fill is visible
    ' before setting it
    .Shapes("Rect2").Fill.Visible = True
    .Shapes("Rect2").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End If

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response and the provided code!
Unfortunately, it didn't work for me. There was a minor typo ("Redt2") which I corrected, but still the Rectangle's color does not update. I double checked the object names and slides, but I haven't been able to find out what seems to be PP's problem here.

Comment: Sorry about the typo; I've edited that out.  The code works here. Have you tried stepping through it?  Is the code in the same presentation as the rectangles?  If not you'd need to make sure that the presentation with the rectangles is currently active

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer and sorry for the delay, I was on a work trip. Interesting that it works for you, I'd like to find out the problem. So what I've done: create a new PPT, add 2 Rectangles, rename them via the Selection Pane to Rect1 and Rect2, go to the VBA screen, add a new macro and paste your code. Then go back to the PPT and Write RED into Rect 1. Should something happen at this stage? Because for me, nothing is happening.

Comment: Without adding somewhat tricky event-handling code, PowerPoint won't do anything just because you changed some text. You need to change the text then run the code to pick up and respond to the change.

Comment: Ohh, so THAT's the problem. That's really unfortunately, it means I cannot really replicate the very user-friendly (becuase: instant) xls solution in ppt. Unfortunately, the person I'm creating this slide for is completely tech-illiterate, so asking them to run any VBA scripts will be completely out of the question. Thank you so much for your help, though, I've learned a lot through this!